# In a time series based load prediction problem, how to deal with missing values

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, prediction

I am analyzing an aws log file with http request logs, and I need to predict the expected load (number of requests) in the next minute. However, I see there are spans of times that doesn't have any logs. In this kind of case, do I assume that loads during those times were just 0, or do I need to do some sort of interpolation?

```
time                     load
-----------------------------------
2018-11-07 09:45:00      40
2018-11-07 09:46:00      45
2018-11-07 09:47:00      34
2018-11-07 09:48:00      56
```

and then no logs for the next 2 hours and then again:

```
time                     load
-----------------------------------
2018-11-07 11:50:00      54
2018-11-07 11:51:00      34
2018-11-07 11:52:00      23
2018-11-07 11:53:00      21
```

Let's say when I read this file to a pandas dataframe for my prediction model, do I fill in all the minutes for those 2 hours with 0? Or are there better intelligent ways of dealing with this sort of situations?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest filling missing values with -1. An ML model should learn to deal with that. When filling the values with a running mean or other interpolation methods, you enforce a function that might not appropriately represent the data. The model should learn itself to deal with missing values (and find the best possible way to interpolate between meassured values).

Here I have an example how it could look like: The model takes the last 5 timesteps to predict the subsequent future timestamp.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

timeline = np.array([40, 45, 50, 53, 54, None, None, None, 50, 43, 30, 
                     20, 15, 14, 13, 14, 16, 21, 27, 35, 46, 59, 65, 70, 
                     None, None, 74, 72, 70, 65, 56, 44, 32, 26, 21, 18, 
                     17, 16, 16, 17, 23, None, 47, 60, 75, None, 105, 
                     111, 116, 118, 119, 118, 112, 103, None, None, 
                     60, 53, 51, 52, 55, 62, None, 75, 77, 76, 74, 63, 
                     50, 35])

plt.figure()
plt.plot(timeline)
plt.xlabel("time_index")
plt.ylabel("requests")
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
timeline[timeline==None] = -1

def get_training_data(timeline, n_time_steps=5):
    x = []
    y = []
    for i in range(n_time_steps, len(timeline)):
        x.append(timeline[i-n_time_steps:i])
        y.append(timeline[i])
    return np.array(x), np.array(y)

x, y = get_training_data(timeline)

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
model = RandomForestRegressor()

# train model
model.fit(x, y)

pred = model.predict([y[-5:]])[0]
print 'the prediction for the future timestamp is:', pred
```

> the prediction for the future timestamp is: 30.8

now if you have unknown values that also works:

```
model.predict(np.array([[10, 20, 30, -1, -1]]))
```

> 46.5

**Note:**

Typically not a Random Forrest but Recurrent Neural Networks (e.g. LSTMs) are used for time-series tasks like this. However, for simplicity, I chose a simpler model.

Comment: But how exactly is filling with -1 helping in terms of prediction?

Comment: I added some description and an example to make clear what I mean

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to fill missing dates with a rolling mean. Otherwise if you where to fit the model with other values for missing dates, say `0`, the model would likely also take these values into account in order to predict, (given that there is no predictability on which dates will have missing values), which would surely worsen the prediction results.

So say you have:

```
  time                 load
0 2018-11-07 09:45:00    40
1 2018-11-07 09:46:00    45
2 2018-11-07 09:47:00    34
3 2018-11-07 09:49:00    56
```

You could start by resampling the dataframe using [`.resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html), and fill the missing values using [`.rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html), which will fill with the rolling mean of a given window length:

```
df.time = pd.to_datetime(df.time)
resampled = df.set_index('time').resample('Min').first()
fill = resampled.rolling(3,center=True,min_periods=1).mean()
resampled.fillna(fill)

                    load
time                     
2018-11-07 09:45:00  40.0
2018-11-07 09:46:00  45.0
2018-11-07 09:47:00  34.0
2018-11-07 09:48:00  45.0
2018-11-07 09:49:00  56.0
```

Answer (score 0):

use tsclean(), it will automatically deal with missing value and outliers.